# How to handle semaphore after WAIT_TIMEOUT

Tags: c++, winapi

Currently I am working on a C++ Project where created a Semaphore using below API.

```
m_hSem = ::CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL);
```

And checking signaling object for timeout using below API

```
if (::WaitForSingleObject(m_hSem, 3000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    //Request time out
}
```

If timeout occurred then do I need to release the semaphore?

Answer (score 2):

> If timeout occurred then do I need to Release the Semaphore?

No, because the wait did not successfully decrement the semaphore's counter, so do not release the semaphore to increment its counter.  Call `ReleaseSemaphore()` only if `WaitForSingleObject()` returned `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.

From  Microsoft's documentation on [Semaphore Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/semaphore-objects):

> A semaphore object is a synchronization object that maintains a count between zero and a specified maximum value. **The count is decremented each time a thread completes a wait for the semaphore object and incremented each time a thread releases the semaphore**. When the count reaches zero, no more threads can successfully wait for the semaphore object state to become signaled. **The state of a semaphore is set to signaled when its count is greater than zero, and nonsignaled when its count is zero**.
>
> ...
>
> Each time one of the [wait functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/wait-functions) returns because **the state of a semaphore was set to signaled**, the count of the semaphore is decreased by one. The [`ReleaseSemaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasesemaphore) function increases a semaphore's count by a specified amount.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I will go through all those links and try to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> If timeout occurred then do I need to Release the Semaphore?

No.  The wait is deemed to have failed in this case.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-semaphore-objects) is a little misleading in the way it is worded but the example code is clear enough.